# Can not use command New-ADuser with new created attribute on AD Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I created a new attribute following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaqIeNnxVU0).

I can edit the attribute that I created in "AD User and Computer" in the "Attribute Editor" (like the clip)

However, I cannot create the new user with that attribute.

The error below:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-ADUser bachhv2 -givenName Bach2
-employeeSex Male New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'employeeSex'. At line:1 char:37
+ New-ADUser bachhv2 -givenName Bach2 -employeeSex Male
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx you're missing a switch between `New-ADUser` and `bachhv2` ... Perhaps `-SamAccountName` ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Can not use command New-ADuser with new created attribute on AD Windows Server 2012**
>
> I can edit the attribute that I created in "AD User and Computer" in the
>   "Attribute Editor"
>
> But, I cannot create the new user with that attribute.

So you created a new attribute in AD per the [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaqIeNnxVU0) video so use the [New-ADUser](http://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html) with the parameter **-OtherAttributes** specifying the *attribute name* and the *attribute value* you want to assign to it, and not the name of the attribute you created as the parameter.

The issue is indicated in the PowerShell error message for the part saying:

> New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   employeeSex'.`

Try this command instead of what you tried when you got that error:

```
New-ADUser bachhv2 -givenName Bach2 -OtherAttributes @{'EmployeeSex'=Male}
```

---

**See [New-ADUser](http://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html)**

```
  -OtherAttributes hashtable
        Specifies object attribute values for attributes that are not represented by cmdlet parameters.
        Syntax:
        To specify a single value:
           -OtherAttributes @{'AttributeLDAPDisplayName'=value}
        To specify multiple values
           -OtherAttributes @{'AttributeLDAPDisplayName'=value1,value2,...}

        e.g.:
           -OtherAttributes @{'ItemPrice'=123; 'favColors'="red","blue"}
```